# How to Update ShockWave Flash Add-Ons in FireFox?

Tags: firefox, updates, flash-player, firefox-extensions

I currently have v10.1.8.53 of the Shockwave Flash Add-on installed in Firefox v3.5.19.

I want to update the add-on to the latest version so I downloaded the installer .exe and ran the installation. However the version of the add-on in Firefox didn't update. Is there any way to update it *manually*?

My default browser is Internet Explorer 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This page](http://www.adobe.com/shockwave/download/alternates/#sp) should be helpful. (I believe you can choose the `Netscape` installer.)